# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'field list'

Tags: php, magento, pdo

I am getting error in magento and not able to resolve.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'field list'

The query was:

```
SELECT
    FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 AS `range`, 
    COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `mag_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN 
    `mag_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON 
    cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND 
    cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '4'
INNER JOIN `mag_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON 
    price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND 
    price_index.website_id = '1' AND 
    price_index.customer_group_id = 0 
GROUP BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 
ORDER BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 ASC
```

> #0 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>   #1 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>   #2 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>   #3 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
>   #4 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
>   #5 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(811): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>   #6 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php(282): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
>   #7 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(158): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price->getCount(Object(Vestique_Mobile_Model_Layer_Filter_Price), 10)
>   #8 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getRangeItemCounts(10)
>   #9 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/local/Vestique/Mobile/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(89): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getPriceRange()
>   #10 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/local/Vestique/Mobile/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(52): Vestique_Mobile_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->_getItemsData()
>   #11 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Vestique_Mobile_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->_initItems()
>   #12 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
>   #13 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
>   #14 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/design/frontend/vestique/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(46): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
>   #15 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/mnt/vhosts/ves...')
>   #16 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/vestiq...')
>   #17 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   #18 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   #19 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   #20 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
>   #21 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   #22 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
>   #23 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/design/frontend/vestique/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
>   #24 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/mnt/vhosts/ves...')
>   #25 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/vestiq...')
>   #26 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   #27 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   #28 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   #29 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
>   #30 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
>   #31 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
>   #32 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
>   #33 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   #34 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   #35 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   #36 /mnt/vhosts/vestiquenew/public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   #37 {main}

Comment: The query looks for the column `min_price` on the `mag_catalog_product_entity` table but that column does not exist.

Comment: Simply it means that 'min_price' column doesn't exists inside 'mag_catalog_product_entity' table

Comment: `min_price` not contain in `mag_catalog_product_entity` table. Check that http://prntscr.com/8qtv5k

Comment: How to resolve this error. @DNReNTi

Comment: is it a custom query?

Comment: Yes, min_price field does contain in mag_catalog_product_entity table but this is not custom query written by me. This error is given by magento.

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: have you cheeked `mag_catalog_product_entity` table for that column name?

Comment: Yes, But it does not contain min_price field.

Comment: I have disabled all custom extension, flush all cache and re-index from admin panel but this error is still coming in fontend.

Comment: I resolved this issue and this is due to Sweet Tooth Extension.